# Xamarin Forms как последовательно открывать больше 2 страниц в приложении?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Подскажите пожалуйста, архитектура приложения на Xamarin Forms такова, что пользователь последовательно переходит с одной страницы на другую.

С открытием первой страницы - проблем особых не возникло.
В `App.xaml.cs` добавил

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

И с главной страницы MainPage.xaml.cs пользователь переходит на страницу со списком.
Тут всё нормально. Проблем нет.

```
App.Current.MainPage = new Page1(); // без навигации
```

или

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1()); // с навигацией
```

или потому, что дальше при выборе позиции из ListView, должно открыться следующее окно:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(e.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Но, я получаю такую ошибку:

***System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.***

:(

Перечитал кучу решений, перепробовал, но без особого успеха.
Многие примеры состоят только из 2х страниц. У меня не получилось найти пример с тремя и более страницами, что бы разобраться в нём.

Может что-то я не учёл?
Может так вообще не делается?

Буду очень рад совету!
Спасибо!

Comment: У вас проблема возникает только в проекте с Android?

Comment: Да. Пока в нём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы вызываете

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(e.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

со страницы Page1. Но PushAsync необходимо вызывать с корневой страницы, то есть MainPage.
Рекомендую вам добавить класс, управляющий навигацией. Например,

```
public static class NavigationService
{
    private static Application CurrentApplication
    {
        get { return Application.Current; }
    }

    public static async Task NavigateToAsync(Page page)
    {
        if (CurrentApplication.MainPage is NavigationPage navigationPage)
        {
            await navigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда вызов на страницу Page 1 будет таким:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(new Page1());
```

С Page 1 на Page 2:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(new Page2(e.Item.ToString()));
```

Comment: Большое Вам Спасибо!!! Всё получилось! :)

Comment: Рад был помочь:)